# Cannot pass object with array property to MVC controller method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have the following controller method signature:

```
public void DiscoveryMailboxAnnotate(string note, List<string> ids)
```

And I am trying to post the following javascript object to this method:

```
  var data = {
                note: 'note',
                ids: ['1','2']
            };
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Supervise/DiscoveryMailboxAnnotate',
                    data: data,
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    },
                    success: function (response) {

                    }
                });
```

The **note** parameter in my controller method is populated but not the **`List<string>` id** parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have ids every where and am not using id anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you've got a model binding problem, try changing to a 
`List<int>` 
on your method signature and think you'll find that works.

Edit:
But it was a model biding issue. Properties are private by default, so change your view model so they are public:

```
        public class DiscoveryMailboxAnnotateViewModel
    {
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public List<string> Ids { get; set; }
    }
```

Then fix your controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void DiscoveryMailboxAnnotate(DiscoveryMailboxAnnotateViewModel model) 
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
        }   
    }
```

Then JQuery

```
<script>
var model = {
    Note: 'note',
    Ids: ['11', '20', '30']
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Home/DiscoveryMailboxAnnotate',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    },
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```

This article will explain more, binding a List didn't do work exactly how I expected: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: But look at the array of ids, they are strings

Comment: Thanks this helped as it is so late at night and this is driving so crazy that I didn't realize the properties where private so public was a good tip. But the parsing is exactly the same where with the view model as with declaring the parameters as part of the controller signature. Note is populated but the List<string> or List<int> Ids is null, I tried both types.

Comment: The above is working on a scrach project, note I did change the property names to match C# convention and the JS too.  Pastebined the code here: http://pastebin.com/Sq0u2ZPC

Comment: After adding contentType: 'application/json', it worked, what a nightmare, thanks!

Comment: Np, we've all been there late at night! :)